# Migrating Far Manager settings from another machine

Tags: far-manager

Is there an easy way to export/import settings for another machine’s instance of Far?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For Far Manager ver. 3.0:

Export settings:

```
Far.exe /export settings.cfg
```

Import settings:

```
Far.exe /import settings.cfg
```

Comment: The "F2 User Menu" items have not been exported.

Comment: F2 Menu is here: `"%APPDATA%\Far Manager\Profile\FarMenu.ini"`

Answer (score 8):

For version 2:

1. Run SaveSettings.cmd from Far installation folder.
2. Copy FarSave1.reg and FarSave2.reg to target machine.
3. Run RestoreSettings.cmd there.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 all configs are located here:

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Far Manager
```

Just copy it to another PC.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Far.exe.ini` for these purposes:

```
;UseSystemProfiles lets you control the location of Far configuration files.
;When 1, configuration will be stored in
;%APPDATA%\Far Manager - for general configuration
;and
;%LOCALAPPDATA%\Far Manager - for history and cache
;When 2, configuration will be stored only in %APPDATA%\Far Manager
;When 0, configuration will be stored in UserProfileDir, UserLocalProfileDir
;The default is 1
;
UseSystemProfiles=0


;UserProfileDir/UserLocalProfileDir lets you define a custom location for Far configuration files.
;Takes effect only when UseSystemProfiles=0.
;The default for UserProfile is %FARHOME%\Profile
;By default UserLocalProfileDir == UserProfileDir
;
UserProfileDir=%FARHOME%\Profile
UserLocalProfileDir=%APPDATA%\Far Manager
```